# Boundness criteria of coloured petri nets

Tags: algorithm, model-checking, petri-net

Is there an algorithm to check the boundness criteria (meaning that the state space is finite) for coloured petri nets (or is this property not decidable)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the construction algorithm for the state graph aborts if the state space is infinite.
Basically, what it does is that it checks for every state that it reaches if there is another state that has strictly smaller marking (so smaller in at least one component and smaller or equal in all components) that can reach the current marking. If so the net has - due to the monotony property of petri nets - an infinite state space.